# How to trigger Svelte component update when imported variable changes

Tags: javascript, svelte

Svelte allows conditional rendering based on the value of a variable in component scope. However, if a variable is imported, Svelte will not trigger an update upon the value change.

What is the proper way to trigger an update in this case ?

Example:

`App.svelte`

```
<script>
    import {flag, setFlag} from './flag.js'
</script>

{#if flag}
    <h1>Flag present</h1>
{/if}

<button on:click={e =>setFlag()}>Toggle</button>
```

`flag.js`

```
export let flag = false
export function setFlag() {
    flag = true;
}
```

When clicking the button, the variable in `flag.js` changes, but the component does not re-render with the new value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use stores to do this.
The code would like like this:
*flag.js*

```js
import { writable } from 'svelte/store';
export const flag = writable(false);
export function setFlag() {
 flag.set(true);
}
```

*App.svelte*

```html
<script>
    import {flag, setFlag} from './flag.js'
</script>

{#if $flag}
    <h1>Flag present</h1>
{/if}

<button on:click={e =>setFlag()}>Toggle</button>
```

Note the use of `$` to mark that you want the *value* of the store and not the store itself.

This is with using your code where you have this `setFlag` function, you could also set the store directly:

```html
<button on:click={() => $flag = true}>Toggle</button>
```

Comment: It was quite confusing for me but if you use an object in writable() you don't need to use set etc. functions